# eliminar duplicados de una hoja de excel

Tags: vba

tengo datos numericos en la hoja 2 y lo que necesito es eliminar los datos duplicados, manteniendo el primer dato y eliminando los restantes y aquellos restantes ordenarlos en hoja 3 de acuerdo a imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo este codigo para eliminar pero como lo adapto a la hoja

```html
Sub Eliminar_repetidos()
Dim Dic, C As Range, Mat, Q&, i&, R&

Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
On Error Resume Next
  For Each C In [a1].CurrentRegion
    If C <> "" Then Dic.Add C.Value, 0
  Next
On Error GoTo 0
Dic = Dic.keys: Q = UBound(Dic)
ReDim Mat(0 To Int(Q / 24), 0 To 23)
Do
  Mat(Int(i / 24), i - 24 * Int(i / 24)) = Dic(i)
  i = 1 + i
Loop Until i > Q

With [a1].CurrentRegion
  With .Cells(1).Offset(1 + .Rows.Count).Resize(1 + UBound(Mat), 24)
    Application.Goto .Cells(1).Offset(-2), True
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = Mat
  End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: y que intentaste hasta el momento?

Comment: pues tengo este codigo para eliminer tocaria adaptarlo pero no se como

Comment: a que te referis con adaptarlo a la hoja? podes cambiar de hoja cada vez que queres...

Comment: el codigo es para eliminar duplicados y quisiera adaptarlo a la imagen 1 en una sola hoja